# Insert images/replace text with images into cells of matplotlib table

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib

Given:

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 20
x = 0.5 * np.random.rand(N)
y1 = 0.2 * np.random.rand(N)
y2 = 0.2 * np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y1, marker='*')
plt.scatter(x, y2, marker='x')

cell_text = [
             ['2020-05-05', '2020-08-25', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-21', '2020-11-03' ],
             ['08:05:10', '19:32:50', '22:55:13', '15:00:00', '09:41:42'],
             ['sun', 'rain', 'night', 'overcast', 'sun']
            ]

cols = ['Test01', 'Test02', 'Test03', 'Test04', 'Test05']
rows = ["Date","Time[GMT]","Weather"]
the_table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                     cellLoc = 'center',
                     rowLabels=rows,
                     rowColours=None,
                     colLabels=cols,
                     loc='bottom')
the_table.scale(1, 3)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

I generate the following plot:

[image]

Now I'd like to replace the `Weather` row (`['sun', 'rain', 'night', 'overcast', 'sun']`) with its corresponding images saved in my directory from [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) such as [image] or [image] and etc.

I thought to replace the its text with its image as follows:

```
emoji_dataset = os.path.join( os.environ['HOME'], 'Datasets', 'Emojis')
for ci, cv in enumerate(cols):
    print(f">> text: { cell_text[2][ci] } => {os.path.join(emoji_dataset, f'{cell_text[2][ci]}.png')}")
    tmp = plt.imread( os.path.join( emoji_dataset, f"{cell_text[2][ci]}.png") )
    #the_table.get_celld()[(3, ci)].get_text().set_text('MyNeWText') # << OK! to change the text
    the_table.get_celld()[(3, ci)].get_text().set_text(tmp)          # << DOES NOT WORK!
```

However, it does not work to replace text with image!

Does anyone know how to insert images into cells of `matplotlib.pyplot.table` ?

Cheers,

Comment: were you able to resolve this?